# Using boost date_time with CLR

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost

I got `Debug Assertion Failed message _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(pUserData)` while starting CLR application that has inclusion of boost library

```
#include "boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian.hpp"
```

Project is compiled usig `/CLR` key.

I have not added any code lines in this project except include ones:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Form1.h"
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>

#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include "boost/date_time/gregorian/gregorian.hpp"


using namespace win_clr;

[STAThreadAttribute]
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    // Enabling Windows XP visual effects before any controls are created
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false); 

    // Create the main window and run it
    Application::Run(gcnew Form1());
    return 0;
}
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: In all likelihood, this is a problem with either your code or the way you linked the standard libraries. Create a minimal SSCCE see whether you can reproduce the problem

Comment: I have added my project code to problem description